# How well does JBox2D work for Android game programming (today)?

Tags: android, game-physics

Is JBox2D fast enough for game programming for Android today (specifically for Froyo and later)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Andengine comes with a full box2d physics extension that uses Box2D and is native (fast). I've used it a few times and it works really well.

You can check out Andengine at http://www.Andengine.org

Edit: You don't need to use andengine with the physics extension if you don't want to and can just use the extension alone but you need to add your own hooks.